# How to write a query to fetch 'Hello World' as 'Hello-World'

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a bit stuck here. I'm actually rewriting URL, All url who have single word seems to work fine but double word name is not working.

Here is my rewrite code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cheap-flights-to-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ flight_details.php?dest=$1 [NC,L]
```

My MySQL Database have a table column *dest_name* with the values like for example "New York, Hong Kong, Kuala Lumpur etc."

Here is my Query

```
    $flights_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fares` WHERE `dest_name`='$to_dest' AND `dept_code`='$from_airport' AND `ticket_class`='Y/Y' AND `fare_type`='$flight_type' ORDER BY fare+tax limit 15");

    while($flights_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($flights_query)) {
        $fares = $flights_fetch['fare'] + $flights_fetch['tax'];
        $addpercent = ($fares * $percent) / 100;
        $final_fares = number_format($fares + $addpercent,2);
    }
```

When I output I add hyphen using PHP function... But it's not fetching data...

Comment: Please [edit] your question, do not write comments.

Comment: So for example you want “hello word” as “ hello-word” in your output?

Comment: No, i want data to be fetched if my URL replace space with a hyphen - if it makes sense. How it is allowed to share URL here so you can understand better

Comment: This works [link](http://falconflight.co.uk/cheap-flights-to-bangkok)
This doesn't [link](http://falconflight.co.uk/cheap-flights-to-hong-kong)
see URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would process the variable before the query. So `$to_dest` would be cleaned before you used in it the query.

```
$to_dest = str_replace(" ", "-", $to_dest);
```